# Camel - Poll rest endpoint and split JSON list

Tags: apache-camel, unmarshalling, polling

So I have a rest API that lives at https://foo.bar/api which returns either an empty json list `[]` or a list that contains 1 or more items:

```
[
    {
        "@class": "foo.bar.java.MyObject",
        "name": "Joe Bloggs"
    },
    {
        "@class": "foo.bar.java.MyObject",
        "name": "Fred Flinstone"
    }
]
```

Now I am trying to have camel take in this data from my endpoint and hand each object within the list to a processor. I've tried the following:

```
fromF("timer://foo-poll?fixedRate=true&delay=5s&period=%d&bridgeErrorHandler=true", pollRate)
    .toF("https4://%s/%s", host, requestPath)
    .log("Received: ${body}")
    .split()
        .jsonpath("$")
        .log("Split: ${body}")
    .process(barProccessor);
```

As well as various attempts to unmarshal the data using `.unmarshal(new ListJacksonDataFormat(MyObject.class))` or `.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, List.class)`
where nothing has worked.

Using the larger code block above, there are no errors nor is the "Split: ${body}" log message printers out.

Unmarshalling using either methods described above throws this regardless of how many items are returned from the API:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No
>   content to map due to end-of-input

When there

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: @CamelDev, I have updated my question with my findings

Answer (score 0):

Okay, managed to figure this out if anyone else is facing a similar issue. The working route builder:

```
fromF("timer://foo-poll?fixedRate=true&delay=5s&period=%d&bridgeErrorHandler=true", pollRate)
    .toF("https4://%s/%s", host, requestPath)
    .log("Received: ${body}")
    .streamCaching("true")
    .unmarshal(new ListJacksonDataFormat(MyObject.class))
    .split()
        .jsonpath("$")
        .log("Split: ${body}")
    .process(barProccessor);
```

I have enabled stream caching and unmarshalled the list using Jackson.